# How to access sqlite database from a service in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating an android application that will show posts from an administrator ( has different subcategories for posts). Whenever there is a new post the users subscribed will get a new notification.

Implemented using mosquitto server mechanism.

**For that I need to access the local database from the service.** I've gone through many blogs but couldn't get it right. I'm a newbie  to android.

Anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: This sentence is confusing: "I need to access the local database from the server".  Are you trying to say that you need to send your local data to a server, or is it something else?

Comment: Please elaborate more " I need to access the local database from the server" . Unable to get clear idea of your problem.

Comment: Sorry. Thats from service. A connection from service to sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

I think a direct accesss from the Web to the Database is not possible, but maybe you can register your App as an Background Process, which connects regular to your Server and send the needed Informations ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pacnos, by the way I need to access sqlite from service. Sorry for typing mistake.